# Skew-symmetric implies alternating for $2$ a zero divisor in $R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, multilinear-algebra, exterior-algebra

In Keith Conrad's notes: https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/extmod.pdf

Theorem 2.10 reads:

> Let $k\geq 2$. If $2\in R^\times$, then a multilinear function $f:M^k \to N$ which is
>   skew-symmetric is alternating.

After the theorem he says

> Strictly speaking, the assumption that $2\in R^\times$ could be weakened to $2$ not being a zero
>   divisor in $R$.

Why is this condition not "$2\notin\text{ann}_R(x)$ for any $x\in N$", i.e., $2$ is not a zerodivisor of $N$? I thought the key line is 
$$2f(m,m,m_3,\ldots,m_k)=0\implies f(m,m,m_3,\ldots,m_k)=0$$
(which is true if $2\in R^\times$).

However, if $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and $N=\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, then if $f(m,m,m_3,\ldots,m_k)=2$, $2f(m,m,m_3,\ldots,m_k)=0\;\not\!\!\!\implies f(m,m,m_3,\ldots,m_k)=0$, even though $2$ is a nonzerodivisor of $R$ (but here $2$ is a zerodivisor of $N$).

But Wikipedia backs up his point, and it's Keith Conrad, so I'm probably missing something obvious or confusing definitions...

Comment: Sorry, I have had tensors in mind lately and that influenced my answer. I'll think about it more. Maybe there is an inaccuracy or missing assumption after all.

Comment: Can you point to the Wikipedia article?  I am inclined to agree that the Conrad's weakening goes too far (i.e. neglects the possibility of torsion elements in $N$).  I'm also puzzled why the definition of 'alternating' is restricted to $k\ge 2$, since it is natural (and useful) to extend it to all $k$.

Comment: Where does Wikipedia back up what I had written?  I wish you had included an actual link there. Anyway, I edited the paragraph  after the theorem to fix the error.