# Alternation, symmetry and skew-symmetry in the case of $R$-modules

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules, multilinear-algebra, exterior-algebra

I'm reading *Algebra I* by Gorodentsev and I'm having trouble untangling the relationships between alternation, symmetry and skew-symmetry. I will not show all of my work below for brevity's sake.

Let $M$ be an arbitrary module over commutative ring with unity $R$.

**Definition:** Multilinear map $\omega \colon \prod_{i = 1}^n M \to R$ is *alternating* if

\begin{align*}
        \omega(m_1, \dots, m_i, \dots, m_j, \dots, m_n) = -\omega(m_1, \dots, m_j, \dots, m_i, \dots, m_n).
\end{align*}

**Definition:** Multilinear map $\omega \colon \prod_{i = 1}^n M \to R$ is *skew-symmetric* if it's zero whenever at least two of its arguments coincide.

**Definition:** Multilinear map $\omega \colon \prod_{i = 1}^n M \to R$ is *symmetric* if it's invariant under permutations of its arguments.

**Claims relating skew-symmetry and alternation:** Skew-symmetry always implies alternation. Alternation implies skew-symmetry when the characteristic of $R$ is $2$, *and* $1_R + 1_R$ is not a zero divisor of $R$. **Are these claims correct?**

**Claims relating symmetry and alternation:** When the characteristic of $R$ is $2$, symmetry and alternation are the same.

**I am unsure if this latter claim is true, and if so, how to show it.** I'll show my work for this below. Consider alternating, multilinear map $\omega \colon \prod_{i = 1}^n M \to R$. Then

\begin{align*}
    \omega(m_1, \dots, m_i, \dots, m_j, \dots, m_n) &= -\omega(m_1, \dots, m_j, \dots, m_i, \dots, m_n)\\
    \implies \omega(m_1, \dots, m_i, \dots, m_j, \dots, m_n) + \omega(m_1, \dots, m_j, \dots, m_i, \dots, m_n) &= 0_R.
\end{align*}

I'm unsure of what to do at this point. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

The terminology for skew-symmetric and alternating you describe in that book looks backwards to me. For $n \geq 2$, I'd say an  $n$-multilinear mapping is *alternating* when it vanishes on all $n$-tuples having an equal pair of coordinates and *skew-symmetric* when it changes sign after the values in any two different coordinate positions of an $n$-tuple are swapped.

With this in mind, I'd express your first claim as "alternating implies skew-symmetry".  For the other direction, keeping in mind the meaning I use for the terms, I'd say "skew-symmetry implies alternating when $2$ is a unit", **not** when $2 = 0$ ("characteristic is $2$").

See Definition 2.1 and Theorems 2.7, 2.8, and 2.10 [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/extmod.pdf). (The proof of Theorem 2.10 shows the condition that $2$ is a unit can be weakened to (edit) $2n = 0 \Rightarrow n = 0$ in the module $N$, and there is a comment about that in the paragraph right after the proof.)

Are you sure you correctly wrote the definitions of both alternating and skew symmetry from Gorodentsev's book? For example, one of the axioms for a Lie algebra over the real or complex numbers is often expressed as $[y,x] = -[x,y]$, but for Lie algebras over fields of characteristic $2$ this condition is useless and the correct definition of a Lie algebra over a general field should have $[y,x] = -[x,y]$ (skew symmetry) replaced by $[x,x] = 0$ (alternating) and this is called an alternating condition on the Wikipedia page on Lie algebras.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I quote part of Definition 9.2 on p. 207: "A Map... is called a *skew-symmetric multilinear form* if it is linear in each argument and vanishes if some arguments coincide." Do you know anything about when symmetry and skew-symmetry (using your terminology) are the same? I think it might be true when the characteristic of $R$ is $2$, but I'm not sure. (No pressure to respond to this.)

Comment: Symmetry and skew-symmetry mean the same thing if $1=-1$, or equivalently $2 = 0$. Concerning the definition of skew-symmetric, I found the definition on p. 207 as you indicated, and the front matter of the book says it is a translation of an edition published in Russia in 2013, but in the 2011 edition online at http://vyshka.math.ru/pspdf/textbooks/gorodentsev/algebra-1.pdf the definition of a skew-symmetric multilinear form is on p. 171 (Definition 10.2) and the property there is described as changing the sign (меняет знак) when any two arguments are exchanged. Weird.

Comment: I found an updated version of Gorodentsev's book on the webpage for his algebra course in Fall 2013, the part about multilinear forms is posted to https://ium.mccme.ru/postscript/f13/algebra1-lec-09.pdf, and it matches what you saw: it appears there as Definition 9.2 on the bottom of p. 132 (2nd page) and the key property is vanishing (обращается в нуль) when two arguments are equal.

Comment: By "$2$ not being a zero divisor in $R$," do you mean that $2$ does not annihilate any elements of $M$? Another [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3122092/skew-symmetric-implies-alternating-for-2-a-zero-divisor-in-r) asks about this, and even gives a potential counterexample, considering $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$ as a $\mathbb Z$-module.

Comment: @WillG that was a mistake.  I have edited that sentence in the file.